# CountDownTimer won't display

Tags: android, android-layout, countdowntimer

```
package com.android.tapme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class TapMe extends Activity {

private int countValue=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tap_me);
    checkTapValue();
}
private void checkTapValue()
{
    Button tapButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tapButton);
    tapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countValue++;
            TextView textView;
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(countValue)); 
        }
    });     

}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    checkTapValue();
}
}
     class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
TextView tv;
   public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(60000, 1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish(){}
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tv.setText((int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }   
 }
```

This is my .java file. The countdown timer should display 60 seconds and count down per second. Thing is everything works fine but the countdown timer. It doesn't display.
Can anyone point out what I did wrong, please?

Also, here's the layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tapButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/tap_me"
    android:textSize="32dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    tools:context=".TapMe" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    tools:context=".TapMe" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT
@imran
I've done this. No difference.

```
class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(60000, 1000);
            }
            private TextView findViewById(int textview2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
            @Override
            public void onFinish(){}
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("" +(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }   
     }
```

Comment: TextView tv=new TextView(this); ????

Comment: why are you repeating the same question again and again ?  this post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305930/i-embedded-a-countdown-timer-in-this-code-but-it-didn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this updated code. works just fine. you didn't started the countdown timer at all and never initialized the textview in timer. i changed these errors in below code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TapMe extends Activity {

    private int countValue = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private TextView textView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tap_me);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setTextSize(40);

        checkTapValue();

        MyCount myCount = new MyCount(60000, 1000);
        myCount.start();

    }

    private void checkTapValue() {
        Button tapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tapButton);
        tapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                countValue++;
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(countValue));

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkTapValue();
    }

    class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            System.out.println(millisUntilFinished);
            textView2.setText("" + (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
    }
}
```